# Deriving the formula for multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The PDF for the distribution is

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T {\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})
\right)$$

If I were trying to derive it from scratch, I would start with the univariate Gaussian distribution 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{({x}-{\mu})^2}{\sigma^2})
\right),$$

and do the following:

1. (ignoring the normalisation factor)
2. substitute $(x-\mu)^2$ to $({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})$
3. substitute $\sigma^2$ to $({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T \boldsymbol\Sigma ({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})$, which should be equal to the variance along the direction of $({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})$ and so exactly what I want.

This would result in the following formula

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}}
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})}{({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T \boldsymbol\Sigma ({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})})
\right),$$

which doesn't seem right.

My two questions are

- What is the problem with the approach above? Please let me know if it doesn't make sense at all.
- Could you recommend a good derivation of the multivariate Gaussian? (couldn't find anything on `exchange` or `Quora`).

Comment: The multivariate "equivalent" of "$(x-\mu)^2$" would be "$(x - \mu)^{\top}(x-\mu)$". However, the equivalent of $\sigma^2$ would be $\Sigma$, not $(x-\mu)^{\top} \Sigma (x-\mu)$.

Comment: @jibounet Thanks! But, given that $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix, isn't it correct that what I need is the value (a scalar) of the projected variance, which would be $({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T \boldsymbol\Sigma ({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})$?

Comment: No, in the multivariate case, we have a [variance-covariance] matrix instead of a scalar ($\sigma$ or $\sigma^2$ in the univariate case). In order to derive the PDF of the multivariate Gaussian distribution, replacing $(x-\mu)^2 / \sigma^2$ with $(x-\mu)^{\top} \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)$ and $\sigma^2$ with $\Sigma$ is not enough because you're still missing the $\vert \Sigma \vert$ term.

Comment: @jibounet Sorry, do you mean $f(x)=N\frac{({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})}{|\boldsymbol\Sigma|}$? I don't fully get that, but if so, how do you get to the $\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}$ term?

Comment: Have a look at : http://noahgolmant.com/derivationsunivariatemultivariate.pdf

Comment: @jibounet This is very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If putting $({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T \boldsymbol\Sigma ({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})$ made sense, then it would make sense in the univariate case, $(x-\mu)\sigma^2(x-\mu),$ but it doesn't. In the univariate case you have
$$
\sigma^2 = \operatorname{E}( (X-\mu)^2 ).
$$
In the multivariate case you have
$$
\Sigma = \operatorname{E}((X-\boldsymbol \mu) (X-\boldsymbol\mu)^T) = \text{an  $n\times n$ matrix, where $\boldsymbol \mu$ is an $n\times 1$ vector.} 
$$

If $X\sim \operatorname{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $\dfrac{X-\mu} \sigma \sim\operatorname{N}(0,1).$ Similarly if $\boldsymbol X \sim \operatorname{N}(\boldsymbol\mu,\Sigma)$ then $\Sigma^{-1/2}(\boldsymbol X-\boldsymbol\mu) \sim \operatorname{N}(\boldsymbol0,I_n)$ where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

But what is $\Sigma^{-1/2}$? It is a consequence of the finite-dimensional version of the spectral theorem that a nonnegative-definite symmetric real matrix has a nonnegative-definite symmetric real square root, and this is it.

For $\boldsymbol X\sim\operatorname{N}(\boldsymbol 0, I_n),$ the density is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}^n} \exp \left( \frac{-1} 2 x^T x \right).
$$
For $\boldsymbol Y = A\boldsymbol X+\boldsymbol b,$ where $A$ is a $k\times n$ matrix and $b$ is a $k\times 1$ vector, the density is
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}^n} \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt{\det (AA^T)}} \exp\left( \frac{-1} 2 \left( (\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol b)^T (A A^T)^{-1} (\boldsymbol y - \boldsymbol b) \right) \right)
$$
Notice that
$$
\operatorname{var}(Y) = A\Big( \operatorname{var}(X) \Big) A^T = A I_n A^T = A A^T.
$$
So the multiplication by $(AA^T)^{-1}$ corresponds to the division by $\sigma^2.$

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only thing that confuses me is $\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1/2}$ -- it would make sense to me if every element of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ was raised to $-1/2$, i.e. ```Sigma .^ (-1/2)``` in MATLAB, but I don't see where the inverse is coming from.

Comment: @AlexMayorov : The matrix $\Sigma$ has real numbers as entries and is symmetric. That implies that there is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to which the matrix is a diagonal matrix with real entries. And since $\Sigma$ is nonnegative-definite, those diagonal entries are nonnegative. And since we're talking about a density (as opposed to a multivariate normal distribution on some affine subspace of $\mathbb R^n.$ So raise those diagonal entries to the power $-1/2$ and then transform back to the standard basis and you've got it.

Comment: Got it! This is actually really nice! Just one last question, though: I understand your explanation why $({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T \boldsymbol\Sigma ({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})$ shouldn't make sense if one looks at the univariate case, but I don't understand why the idea of using a projected variance (my original motivation for using $({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu})^T \boldsymbol\Sigma ({\boldsymbol x}-{\boldsymbol \mu}))$ isn't valid. I understand your derivation, though -- many thanks for sharing it!

Comment: The variance is $\Sigma = \operatorname{E}( (\mathbf X-\mathbf \mu) (\mathbf X - \mathbf \mu)^T ),$ an $n\times n$ matrix. Does that address your question. $\qquad$